# Insert row in Pandas Dataframe based on a condition

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I'm using Pandas to process huge time series dataset. I would like add row between the rows in the dataframe if the difference between two consecutive indexes is greater than 5.

Actual:

```
            a  result
Date                 
1497544649  1     1.0
1497544652  9     1.0
1497544661  9     NaN
```

Expected:

```
            a  result
Date                 
1497544649  1     1.0
1497544652  9     1.0
1497544657  9     0
1497544661  9     NaN
```

I used *diff()* on index to get difference between two consecutive indexes but not sure how to insert record if the difference is greater than 5.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([{"Date": 1497544649,"a":1, "result": 1}, 
                   {"Date": 1497544652,"a": 9, "result": 1},
                   {"Date": 1497544661,"a": 9, "result": 1}])
df.set_index("Date", inplace=True)

df.index.to_series().diff().fillna(0).to_frame("diff")
```

Any pointers on how to achieve this would be appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have a head start. Add a diff column to allow for easier filtering.

Get indexes for data frames matching your rule and insert your row.

```
df['diff'] = df.index.to_series().diff().fillna(0).to_frame("diff")

matches = df[df['diff'] > 5].index.tolist()


for i in matches:
    diff = df.loc[i]['diff']
    interval = round(diff/2) # index some place in the middle
    df.loc[i-interval] = [0, 0, 0, diff-interval] # insert row before matched index
    df.loc[i]['diff'] = interval # may not need to update the interval

df.sort_index(inplace=False) # pandas appends by default so we should sort this

del df.diff # we can remove this
```